# Embed Image using php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer, sugarcrm

I'm currently creatting a mailer and embed image. So when I set a specific directory ( ./upload/tmp_logo_company_upload/company_logo_resized.jpg ) for image it successfully send to my email and it shows the image that i embed.

But I want is to get all the image in the upload directory so whenever I run the script all images from upload folder will send to me. Can someone help me out for this, Below you will see my code. Thanks.

```
if( !defined('sugarEntry') ) define( 'sugarEntry',true );
    // Set required classes
    require_once('include/entryPoint.php');
    // Get access to globals
    global $db, $current_user, $timedate;

        $arRecipientsId = array();
        $objDefaultMail = new Email();
        $objDefault = $objDefaultMail->getSystemDefaultEmail();
        $objMail = new SugarPHPMailer();
        $objMail->setMailerForSystem();
        $objMail->From = $objDefault['email'];
        $objMail->FromName = $objDefault['name'];
        $objMail->Subject = "";
        // Set the Location of photo
        $strLocation = './upload/tmp_logo_company_upload/company_logo_resized.jpg';
        // Add image
        $objMail->AddEmbeddedImage($strLocation, 'company_logo_resized.jpg');
        //
        $objMail->Body = "Here. <img src='cid:company_logo_resized.jpg'>";
        // Send as HTML
        $objMail->IsHTML(true);
        // Clear previous email data
        $objMail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $objMail->ClearReplyTos();
        $objMail->prepForOutbound();
        // Store recipients
        $arRecipientsId[] = "1"; //crmonline
        // Add as BCC
        $objMail->AddBCC('email@gmail.com');
        // Mail sent? 
        if( $objMail->send() ) {
        // echo "Email Has Been Sent";
        $GLOBALS['log']->fatal("WORKING");
        }
    // }
```

Comment: I didn't understand very well your question. You want to create a directory that every time someone uploads an image to it PHP will mail you that image? Could you edit your question to explain this with more details?

Comment: Hi flen I edit my question again to make it clear. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to call `ClearAllRecipients` or `ClearReplyTos` - the things those clear are already empty because you have a new instance.

To iterate over all the files in a folder, use a [DirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php) - that will get all the filenames you need, so you just need to call `addEmbeddedImage` for each and add `<img src="cid:xxx">` tags for each image you want to embed.

```
$dir = './upload/tmp_logo_company_upload';
$cidn = 0;
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($dir) as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot() or $fileInfo->isDir()) continue;
    $objMail->addEmbeddedImage($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileInfo->getFilename(), "img_$cidn");
    $mailObj->Body .= "<img src=\"cid:img_$cidn\">";
    ++$cidn;
}
```

That said, this is an inefficient way of using images in email - it is much better to use HTTP links to the images - that way they are only loaded when the recipients ask for them, rather than sending them regardless.

Comment: Hi Synchro, Appreciate your answer. actually this is now fixed i used query and create a foreach loop to get all the images

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty simple , you are missing complete image public path

change this to following

```
$objMail->Body = "Here. <img src='cid:company_logo_resized.jpg'>";
```

To (Image Public Path including http)

```
$objMail->Body = "Here. <img src='http://example.com/publicppath /company_logo_resized.jpg'>";
```

Adding code for Reading the Image from dir

```
//path to the dir
$dir    = '/upload';
$files = scandir($dir);


foreach ($files as $image) {
    $all_img .= " <img src='http://example.com/imagepath/".$image."'><br>";
}

//for embeding image
foreach ($files as $image) {
    $im = file_get_contents($image);
    $em_img .="<img src='data:image/jpg;base64,".base64_encode($im)."'> <br>"
}

//via public path
$objMail->Body = "Here ".$all_img;

//or embed sending
$objMail->Body = "Here ".$em_img;
```

it should work

Comment: Hi mahesh, appreciate it but i don't have problem with this (  $objMail->Body = "Here. <img src='cid:company_logo_resized.jpg'>"; ). All i want is to get all Images under the upload folder.

Comment: copy all images to upload folder and use public path . sorry i miss understood this

Comment: It's ok, I already copy all images to upload folder but it doesn't work. But when I try to set a specific file it works. example: $strLocation = './upload/tmp_logo_company_upload/company_logo_resized.jpg'

Comment: yes u have to include each image , there is no directory listing available

Comment: Is it possible to call only the folder 'Upload' then all the image under it will be populate? Like mass sending.

Comment: yes write a for loop to create required <img > tags

Comment: This is entirely wrong - it's referencing external images loaded remotely, not using embedded images at all.

Comment: i have added the embedded support to

Comment: Images in data URLs don't work in some email clients. External linked images are the most efficient and most reliable. Neither are what the question asked for.